# How can I retrieve unique data from a table with father and son relationship on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm have a table with father and son relationship, both, father and son are primary key, let me show you an example of the data :

```
Father | Son
----------------
A      |   1
A      |   2
B      |   1
C      |   1
D      |   2
E      |   3
```

So what I want is **group by son**, and get 1 of the fathers, doesn't matter which one, I know it sounds weird, but I only need to know one of the fathers as a reference, so I'm looking for a result like this:

```
Son    | Father
----------------
1      |   A
2      |   A
3      |   E
```

I tried to do something like this, **in my query [code] is the son**

```
select i.father, q1.code from
(select i1.code from itt1 i1 where isnumeric(substring(i1.father, 0, 3)) =1 group by i1.code) q1
left join itt1 i on q1.code = i.code where i.code is null
```

1. I retrieve and group all the sons and encapsulated the result in q1 sub query
2. Then I left join q1 with the table, but I'm not getting the result I want

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: `select son, min(father) from youratbel group by son`

Comment: ooh that was pretty fast, ... thank you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with the group by.  For example:

```
select son, min(father) AS Father from itt1 group by son
```

Comment: Prdp beat me to it by about 30 seconds!

Comment: Ha ha quite easy that's why ;p